# Weird characters when concatenating strings in c

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate multiple strings to create a longer phrase but I get weird, seemingly random, characters in front of the phrase when I try to print it. Here is the code:

```
char* str2 = argv[2];
int len2 = strlen(str2);
char* str3 = argv[3];
int len3 = strlen(str3);
printf("child PID(%d) receives Y = '%s' and Z= '%s' from the pipe\n",getpid(), str2, str3 );

//get the length of arguments 2 and 3 and create an array that is 1 larger than that (for the space between the two phrases)
//then concatenate them
int catLen = len2+len3;
char conc[catLen + 1];
strcat(conc, str2);
strcat(conc," ");
strcat(conc, str3);
printf("child PID(%d) concatenates Y and Z to generate Y' = '%s'\n",getpid(),conc);

int len1;
//get the length of the first command-line argument in the pipe
read(port[0],&len1,sizeof(len1));

//get the first command-line argument from the pipe
char str1[len1];
read(port[0], &str1,len1);
printf("child PID(%d) reads X from the pipe = '%s'\n",getpid(),str1);


//problems start when concatenating strings here        
int totalLen = len1+catLen+1;
char phrase[totalLen];
strcat(phrase, str1);
printf("%s\n",phrase);
strcat(phrase," ");
printf("%s\n",phrase);
strcat(phrase,conc);
printf("child PID(%d) concatenates X and Y' to generate Z' = '%s'\n",getpid(),phrase);
```

I only encounter this issue when I try and concatenate the second set of strings, and I don't understand why. What is different between how I did it earlier and at the bottom the program?

Comment: They both have the same problem. `strcat` requires that both parameters be strings. But both `conc` and `phrase` are unintialised and hence not valid strings. The first one only "works" by chance and not because it is correct code. Add `conc[0] = 0;` and `phrase[0] = 0;` before passing them to their respective first `strcat` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,
as Ptit Xav points out, you need one additional byte of space for `conc`.  You need `len1` bytes for the first string, plus 1 for the space, plus `len2` for the second string, and then one more for the terminating null character.  So if `catLen = len1 + len2`, then you should declare `char cond[catLen + 2];` (or change the calculation of `catLen` in some equivalent way).

---

Next, when you declare a local array like `char conc[catLen + 2];` without initializing it, it contains garbage.  If you then attempt to `strcat` onto it, you concatenate onto garbage.  If the garbage happens not to contain any null bytes, then `strcat` will overrun the array searching for a null byte, causing undefined behavior (which is very bad).

So either make your first use a `strcpy` instead of `strcat`:

```
char conc[catLen + 2];
strcpy(conc, str2);  // note strcpy here
strcat(conc," ");
strcat(conc, str3);
```

Or else set the first character of your array to be a null character before starting, so that it becomes an empty string:

```
char conc[catLen + 2];
conc[0] = '\0';     // conc now contains an empty string
strcat(conc, str2);
strcat(conc," ");
strcat(conc, str3);
```

You can also initialize the array:

```
char conc[catLen + 2] = "";
strcat(conc, str2);
strcat(conc," ");
strcat(conc, str3);
```

However this will cause the program to fill the entire array `conc` with null bytes, where you really only needed one, so it is inefficient.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you must add 1 to catlen because you add a space between str2 and str3. So size of  conc array should be : len2(str2) + 1(space)+len3(str3)+1(\0